# Select which nodes are folded in org mode files when opened

Tags: org-mode

I understand that #+STARTUP: property can control the fold/unfold setting in **file level** when the org file is loaded. But I need it be more granular.

I wonder if it is possible to set it in node level? for example, *node1 has all subitems unfolded, and *node2, *node3 have all subitems folded?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

xuchunyang is right. Just to complete the answer, you can set the `VISIBILITY` property to `children` for the node to develop such as in the following example:

```
 * Node to be unfolded
 :PROPERTIES:
 :VISIBILITY: children
 :END:
```

Comment: Thank you both. Actually I spent sometime to figure out `:Properties:` is needed before `visibility`, your answer is clearer for beginners.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to totally hide `:PROPERTIES:` section in org file. Folding it still displays one line. which is disturbing for other audiences

Comment: [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478260/completely-hide-the-properties-drawer-in-org-mode).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. You can set a `VISIBILITY` property for that node separately, for example, use `M-x org-set-property VISIBILITY ...`.