# org-mode: force heading subtree to start folded

Tags: org-mode

I know `:ARCHIVE:` does this, but I use that tag to mean the subtree is essentially useless now. I want sth like `:FOLD:`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select which nodes are folded in org mode files when opened](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17165/select-which-nodes-are-folded-in-org-mode-files-when-opened)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the initial visibility for a single subtree with the `visibility` property:

```
* My Folded Heading
:PROPERTIES:
:VISIBILITY: folded
:END:
```

You can set initial visibility options for the entire file by including a `STARTUP` directive:

```
#+STARTUP: overview
```

Finally, you can set this globally via the customizable variable `org-startup-folded`

For details, see the manual [(org) Initial visibility](https://orgmode.org/manual/Initial-visibility.html)